# Internal linking to posts permalink fail because of spaces and stripe at postname

Tags: posts, functions, permalinks, links, get-posts

I have written a function which outputs a tag in a textarea in which people can link internally to other posts on the website. This works like a charm except with using a `postname permalink structure`...

For example: people link to a post called **'Hello World'** by writing **(link: Hello World)**... The link to the post, however, is: http://somesite.com/**hello-world**

So what happens? I get a 404-error because it looks like *Hello World* does not exist, but it does! It has just no stripe between it and uppercase letters... My question is: how do I make it link to the proper post? This is the code I am using:

```
 $content = preg_replace('%\(link: ?(.*?) ?\)%', '(link: <a href="http://somesite.com/$postname_test" title="$postname_test">$postname_test</a>)', $content);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces are invalid characters in URLs. Your links *are* broken, whether the posts exist or not and regardless of whether you want the spaces or not.

And uppercase/lowercase can get you in trouble too. Some servers are case sensitive so if you have a permalink to `http://somesite.com/hello-world` a link like `http://somesite.com/Hello-World` might work or it might not. You don't want pages to 404 over case, right?

Your code is out of content so it hard to test but ...

```
$content = "(link: http://example.com/test )"; // assuming links like this
$post= 'Abc Def'; // and assuming $post is the post title

$content = preg_replace(
  '%\(link: ?(.*?) ?\)%', 
  '(link: <a href="http://somesite.com/'.sanitize_title_with_dashes($post).'" title="'.$post.'">'.$post.'</a>)', 
  $content
);
```

There are a couple of things I noticed about your code.

1. `$post` is a global variable used by WordPress. You appear to
   clobbering it by setting it to the post title instead of leaving it
   as the post Object as it should be. I would recommend using a
   different variable name.
2. In PHP, variables do not expand inside single quotes so the parts of
   your code where you had variables inside single quotes would not
   have printed the way you wanted. For example,
   `title="$post">$post</a>)'` would have literally been
   `title="$post">$post</a>)'`

On further thought, rather than convert the title to the permalink the way you are trying to do you'd be better off just using `$post->post_name`, with `$post` being the post Object it should be. WordPress initially converts the title to the permalink the way that I did, but the title can be edited independently of the permalink. There is no guarantee that converting the title will work.

As it turns out the real question is how to capture and convert the user supplied input. For that you need [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

```
function transform_pseudo_anchor_wpse_101201($match) {
  if (isset($match[1])) {
    return '(link: <a href="http://example.com/'.sanitize_title_with_dashes($match[1]).'" title="'.$match[1].'">'.$match[1].'</a>)';
  }
}

$content = preg_replace_callback(
  '%\(link: ?(.*?) ?\)%', 
  'transform_pseudo_anchor_wpse_101201', 
  $content
); 
echo $content;
```

Comment: Yes, I know that it is invalid, but the problem is that the registered users can link to the internal posts, so they are not going to check if it exists or not... If it does not exist; than show a 404 error. But if it exists, but written without the obvious spacing and uppercase, I want it to show me.

Comment: I know, I just edited the variable here because it was a very long word...

It did not work btw. It just removes the link now.

Comment: Your first comment is very, very confusing but if you want to know how to "make it link to the proper post", I just told you.

Comment: What is confusing?

The goal of the site is to link to posts, whether they exist or not... The problem is that if they write "Hello World" in the tag, they don't get the post on the page /hello-world --> No, they also get a 404 error. That should not happen, because the post exists, but is just written differently (because of the stripe). If it did not exist at all, than this would make sense, but even with sanitize_title_with_dashes it does not seem to work.

It removed the whole link now.

Comment: "What is confusing?"... well, you want to " link to posts, whether they exist or not". That for one. And the fact that you seem to think that invalid URLs are just "written differently" and should still work. The code I posted works exactly as I pasted it. (You do have to `echo` it of course.) I have no idea what context you are trying to use this in though.

Comment: What I meant is: people can link to whatever they like, because they can write whatever they like. And with written differently I meant the syntax... So if you remove the dash between the two words, it becomes the same post. That's what I meant...

I know that we are close, but it's not working yet. I pasted your code on my functions.php, editing the link of course, but the a href does not show up...

Comment: I see the a_href via Firebug, but can't see the content of it...

Comment: Note: your code works after adding the $post and $content variable, but I want the users input to be outputted, not a constant ABC Def that is already defined in functions.php...

Sooo the question is: how can I make the $post variable, whatever the user writes?

Comment: "how can I make the `$post` variable, whatever the user writes?"-- That is a very different question than the one you started with! Are you hoping to have the user write something like "(link: Hello World )" and have that convert?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I want.

I only could ask that question if this one was answered :)) 
We (you) are very close now.

Comment: Edit: I managed to get it work with your code. You are truly wonderful. Thank you very much!

Comment: I assume I can make it work for other tags too with the same function? Just copying the code after setting a comma should do the trick.

Once again: thank you very much!